# What does "in two" mean with respect to tempo?

Tags: terminology, time-signatures, tempo

My copy of Leonard Cohen's *Hallelujah* has the following tempo indication:

> Moderately slow, in 2

What does the "in 2" mean? I couldn't find it in [Wikipedia's glossary of musical terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_musical_terminology).

The piece is notated in 6/8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

6/8 is actually 'two time'. Whilst some 6/8 tunes can be counted 123, 456, others will count as 1-- 2--, in the same time. So it's either a quicker count of 6, or a count at a third of the speed of 2. To explain - '1' will be the same in both counts, and '4' in the first is where '2' in the second comes. So this song is a slow two.

Comment: "So it's either a quicker count of 6, or a count at a third of the speed of 2" -- could you explain that in detail, please? Intuitively I would stress 1 and 4 (assuming I'm counting 123456).

Comment: *In two* means two beats per bar, so you are effectively counting dotted quarter notes, Tims minus signs are silent.

Comment: @guidot Thanks for the clarification. Am I correct that within each triplet (123 and 456) only the first note is stressed?

Comment: @FlorianBrucker - yes, stress 1 and 4, which comes down to the same feel as one - two.

Comment: The "official" (copyrighted) version of the sheet music is in 12/8 not 6/8, and doesn't include any tempo instruction except a metronome mark. See "version #2" at http://sheetmusic-free.com/hallelujah-piano-sheet-music-leonard-cohen/. So the "in 2" was presumably added by the re-arranger for reasons best known to him/herself.

Comment: @FlorianBrucker - there are no triplets per se in 6/8 time. It's a triplet feel, but the notes are not written as triplets .

Comment: @alephzero - interesting! To me, it has a tendency to feel 6/8 in the verse and 12/8 in the chorus, so it could be either or both by the feel.

Comment: @alephzero I've bought what I hope is also [an "official" version](http://www.sheetmusicplus.com/title/hallelujah-digital-sheet-music/19433060) that respects copyright. Since there is no separate arranger listed I assumed it to be the original version. But that may very well be not the case.

Comment: @Tim true. counting 6/8 for me tends to be "1-and-a 2-and-a" because it feels like a triplet, but the beat is represented by a dotted quarter not a quarter so this isn't a true triplet

Comment: @FlorianBrucker In pop and rock music, the only 'original version' is the recording.  The creative process may not be notation-based at all.  There may be an 'official' copy published by the rights owner, but it's often only a rough simplification of what was played and recorded.  Often it isn't even in the same key!